Hilbert space equality problem
i have a question regarding one equality, namely,
$$\langle Az,z\rangle =0$$ Where $z\in range A^*=(kerA)^{\bot}$
A is bounded linear operator.
I don't see why should this dot product be zero, Any help is great, thanks!
It is given that $A^2=0$, that iz $ranA\bot ranA^{*}$.
I didn't read that it was given also..

I don't get why it should be $0$ either. Take $A$ the identity operator over your inner product space $V$, then $z$ can be taken anywhere in $range(A^*) = V$. It suffices to take $z\neq 0$ to have $\langle Az,z\rangle = |z|^2 \neq 0$. Did you forget to tell some information that was given? For example is $A$ taken such that $A^2 = 0$?

I updated the question, I forgot to add the information, you are right.

Well now that $A^2 = 0$ is given, we call $V$ your inner product space, and let $z\in range(A^*)$, giving us the existence of $y\in V$ such that $z = A^*y$. Now we compute
$$\langle Az,z\rangle = \langle Az,A^*y\rangle = \langle A^2z,y\rangle = 0.$$
